# Remove directories only command line

Tags: linux, command-line

How to remove folders and there content and keep files in the current directory ?

before

```
parent
├── folder1
├── folder2
│   ├── file1
│   ├── file2
├── folder3
├── file3
├── file4
└── file5
```

after:

```
parent
├── file3
├── file4
└── file5
```

Comment: What is the os you use?

Comment: I'm on a linux machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick

```
cd parent
find . ! -path . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

This will look for directories in the current working dir and only recurse 1 level down and the removes the dirs. Best do a testrun with ls instead of rm before doing this so you can check what will be removed

```
cd parent
find . ! -path . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec ls {} \;
```

*Example*

```
jake@jake-HP /tmp/test $ tree
.
├── 1
├── 2
├── bar
│   ├── 1
│   ├── 2
│   └── 3
├── blah
│   ├── 1
│   ├── 2
│   └── 3
└── foo
    ├── 5
    └── 9

3 directories, 10 files
jake@jake-HP /tmp/test $ find . ! -path . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec ls {} \;
1  2  bar  blah  foo
1  2  3
5  9
1  2  3
jake@jake-HP /tmp/test $ find . ! -path . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec rm -rf {} \;
jake@jake-HP /tmp/test $ tree
.
├── 1
└── 2

0 directories, 2 files
```

Comment: I've just found the solution find . ! -path . -type d | xargs rm -R @Jake `! -path .` is what you're looking for to exclude `.` folder

Comment: thanks ghilas-belhadj ! Edited the answer to include this.

Comment: To test better `-exec ls -dF {} \;`  or `-exec ls --color -dF {} \;` just to avoid to list what inside the directories.

Comment: Warning, the `find | xargs rm` will give unwanted results in the presence of directory names containing spaces or (even worse) special characters.

Answer (score 0):

Using find is good because you specify exactly what you want to be done. However the xargs in Jake's answer has a problem with directory names containing spaces. You'd need to add -print0 to find and -0 to xargs.

I would have written

```
find parent -type d -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec rm -rf '{}' \;
```

This is even simpler:

```
rm -rf parent/*/
```

It won't remove hidden directories (starting with a period) though, you'd need to add them:

```
rm -rf parent/*/ parent/.[^.]*/
```

Watch out if you have symlinks pointing elsewhere, though.

If you don't trust */ to match only directories, a less clean solution that will produce lots of errors (and that does not take into account hidden directories because that gets complicated) is

```
rm -rf parent/*/* 
rmdir parent/*
```

Answer (score 0):

you can give `ls` a chance

I tested on mac

`ls -p | grep  / | xargs  -I _ mv   _   ~/.trash`

easy to do `rm` , since result has been filtered

- move to `~/.trash`, that gives you second chance
- `-v` Don't show matching records

Comment: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: +1. when you ask it for a list of files, there's a huge problem: Unix allows almost any character in a filename,