# How to remove all the folders in the current directory?

Tags: linux, bash

I want to remove all the **folders/directories** in the current folder (and its contents) without touching the files in current folder.

```
find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec rm -r {}
```

Traceback:

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

Comment: add on the end `\;`. TO be come `find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec rm -r {} \;`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove directories only command line](https://superuser.com/questions/1053537/remove-directories-only-command-line)

Answer (score 1):

The post
[How to delete only directories and leave files untouched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953160/how-to-delete-only-directories-and-leave-files-untouched)
has this very simple solution :

> To delete all directories and subdirectories and leave only files in
> the working directory, I have found this concise command works for me:
>
> ```
> rm -r */
> ```
>
> It makes use of bash wildcard `*/` where star followed by slash will
> match only directories and subdirectories.

The above `rm` command will not remove folders whose names start
with a dot (`.`), which is perhaps what most people would prefer.

The formulation recommended by user Romeo Ninov is also found in this post:

> `find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d`
>
> then
>
> `find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec rm -rf '{}' \;`
>
> To add an explanation:
>
> `find` starts in the current directory due to `.` and stays within the
> current directory only with `-maxdepth` and `-mindepth` both set to
> `1`. `-type d` tells `find` to only match on things that are
> directories.
>
> `find` also has an `-exec` flag that can pass its results to another
> function, in this case `rm`. the `'{}' \;` is the way these results
> are passed. [See this answer for a more complete explanation of what
> `{}` and `\;` do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6085272/5889131)

Comment: "bash wildcard `*/` where star followed by slash will match only directories and subdirectories" – Directories in the current working directory, yes, but *not* subdirectories. Subdirectories will be deleted because of `-r`, not because the wildcard matches them. By default `*` does not match dot files, so this solution does not fulfill the "all the folders/directories" requirement. Sadly the answer you cited is superficial. It is highly upvoted because usually it matches expectations, still superficial.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: I think that not deleting dot folders is a good thing.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: Rather than argue, I added this information in my answer.

Comment: In 999‰ of cases (including this one), you want `+` instead of `;`. With a massive number of small directories, this can make a significant difference.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to combine these two `find` incantations

```sh
# delete the contents of directories
find . -depth -mindepth 2 -print -delete

# then delete the directories
find . -mindepth 1 -type d -print -delete
```

Comment: Interesting approach. You cannot combine these exact two because `-mindepth` (like e.g. `-depth`) is a "global" primary that affects how the "traversing engine" of `find` works. AFAIK FreeBSD `find` (but not GNU `find` common in Linux) supports `-depth -n|n|+n` (not related to sole `-depth`) that is actually a test performed for each file separately. This (along with `-o`) allows us to do different things to files at different levels. With FreeBSD `find` we could rewrite the commands using `-depth +1` and `-depth 1` instead of the respective `-mindepth …`, *then* we could combine them.

Comment: (cont) The problem is AFAIK FreeBSD `find` does not support `-delete`, so we would need to use `-exec rm …` instead. And then there is no reason not to use `rm -r` in the first place.